# Mysql Database dump without starting mysql

Tags: mysql

I have mysql installed on my windows 7 machine which has about 30 databases. Now the OS is corrupted due to some reason. I have access through command prompt only. I am unable to start mysql using command prompt or login to mysql or using mysqldump or any other commands. Is there anyway using which I can get the database dump of all databases using some physical file location? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you have your daily backup snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

the database files are in whatever location is specified in the `datadir` variable in your my.cnf file.

On windows, this is likely to be `<mysql directory>\data`

Each database has its own subdirectory which contains the schema definitions, MyIsam stores the table information in these subdirectories as well but InnoDB tables store their data in the ibdata file, unless you had `innodb_file_per_table=1` when the tables were created.

You can try to create a fresh mysql installation and just copy the data dir across - i've had some success doing this in the past. It will be more likely to succeed for any MyISAM tables however